# What happen to the visit rate for Interpersonal.SE site?

Tags: discussion, statistics

For as long as I can remember Interpersonal.SE use to get a few thousands of visiters a day according to the stats page found on Area51, Stack Exchange and the side bar of the site itself.

However it suddenly drop down to the 100s range. Currently it says 275 visits a day on Area 51.

Is there any reason for the sudden drop in traffic? I don't think this has anything to do with the fact that it's close to the weekend. It's been like this for a while.

Answer (score 5):

SE turned off the [tracking cookie as a default cookie](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374897/why-is-the-google-analytics-cookie-defined-as-strictly-necessary-and-saved-wit) so less folks are counted. I could swear there's a specific post covering this but I can't find it

Comment: MSE: [Why has there been such a huge drop in "new visits" since May 9th, 2022, across multiple sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/379047/369802)

Comment: "*so less folks are counted*" -> even the ones who come every single day and lost a day, dropping their fancy internet gaming counter to some consecutive days instead of thousands... :/

Comment: Well no, that's a different thing I think?

Comment: I'm not sure... Unless something went wrong. Seemed related to me. From the late90's to nowadays, under the RGPD, I've been blocking almost all cookies on all websites, and this may be that can impact the results?

Comment: It shouldn't? I mean it should know you're logged in and came to the site.

Comment: "*it should*", right :)

Comment: Yes, but that's a bug, *this* is a feature.